# Access Token Member Ambiguity

Tags: windows, security, authorization, acl, access-token

According to this [article on Access Tokens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374909%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), a token contains several pieces of information, including:

- The security identifier (SID) for the user's account
- An owner SID

I would expect the owner SID and user account SID to be the same.  In what example scenario would they be different?

[Further documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721592%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#_security_logon_sid_gly) explains that the Login SID of an access token is sometimes used in a DACL.  I'd like to know a security "pattern" where a DACL would be assigned an access or deny of a particular Login SID.  At face value, it seems like a far-fetched case.  About the only use I could imagine, would be to deny one logged in user from having visibility about what other users are also logged in.  Is there more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The owner SID [represents the entity that should be designated as the owner of any objects created under the focal token](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379628.aspx).  One of the key scenarios under which one expect the owner SID to differ from the login SID is when the [System objects: Default owner for objects created by members of the Administrators group](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775434%28WS.10%29.aspx) local security policy option is configured so that the Administrators group becomes the owner of objects created by a logged in administrator.

The only really "typical" cases for using a logon SID in a DACL would be when controlling access to a process or a transient resource running under the current logon session.  For details, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david_leblanc/archive/2007/07/29/logon-id-sids.aspx.